# secureCRT VBS using WaitForStrings() and Switch Case

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

This is a script to simulate answers from a machine, my problem is that "WaitForStrings" dosent differentiate between "open" and "open1" or "close" and "close1", he always answers to "open" and "close"

```js
firstopen=true
while(true)
 strResult = crt.Screen.WaitForStrings("open1","close1","open","close","SCAN")
 Select Case strResult
  Case 1
   crt.Sleep 500
   crt.Screen.Send("open1_ok") & chr(13)
  Case 2
   crt.Sleep 500
   crt.Screen.Send("close1_ok") & chr(13)

  Case 3
   If firstopen=true then
    crt.Sleep 500
    crt.Screen.Send("open_ok") & chr(13) 
    firstopen=false
   else
    crt.Sleep 500
    crt.Screen.Send("ok") & chr(13)
    firstopen=true
   end if 
  Case 4
  crt.Sleep 500
  crt.Screen.Send("ready") & chr(13)

  Case 5
  crt.Sleep 500
  crt.Screen.Send("CCD_PASS") & chr(13)
  
  Case Else
  crt.Screen.Dialog "We didn't find what we were looking for"
 
 End Select
wend
```

Comment: So what do you want us to do? We can't change the behaviour of the `WaitForStrings()` method, maybe try `"1open"` and `"1close"` instead and see if it recognizes that. You just need to work with the limitation and find a way around it.

Comment: that is the problem i cant change the expected string...

Comment: Is [`Screen.Synchronous = True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46668176/692942)?

Comment: crt.Screen.Synchronous = True had no effect

Comment: Then my advice is still the same, go away and read the guide, specifically the section [4.2 Waiting for Specific Data to Arrive](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf). The other possibility is what it mentions at the end of that section **Ignoring Escape Codes (Or Not)** which suggests if the output text contains any escape codes the `WaitForStrings()` method will not detect it properly unless `Screen.IgnoreEscape = True` is set *(it's `False` by default)*. All of this information I've gleaned from a quick look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Might be relevant

> <sup>From [A Guide to Using VBScript in SecureCRT - Page 41 *(excerpt)*](https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/scripting/scripting_essentials.pdf)</sup>
>   ***Avoid "Missing" Data with `Screen.Synchronous = True`***
>
> *In order to avoid the potential for `WaitForString()` and its related methods to miss data that
>   is sent from the remote while other code within your script is being executed, it's important to
>   know about the `Synchronous` property associated with the `Screen` object. You may have
>   seen `Screen.Synchronous = True` statements appear within some of the sample code
>   you've seen earlier in this document; this section attempts to explain when it would be important
>   to use such statements within your code.*
>
> *...*
>
> *If your script code seems to be "missing" data that appears on the screen, inspect your code
>   and ensure that the `Synchronous` property of the `Screen` object with which you are working is
>   set to `True`.
>   Be aware, however, that setting `Screen.Synchronous` to `True` can seem to have an impact
>   on SecureCRT's performance because data will not be displayed to the screen until calls to
>   `WaitForString`, `WaitForStrings`, `ReadString`, or `WaitForCursor` are made. For
>   example, the following script code will result in a successful connection to the remote host, but
>   nothing will be displayed to the terminal window since the script is looping forever (without
>   making any calls to `ReadString`, `WaitForString`, `WaitForStrings`, or `WaitForCursor`).*

Answer (score 0):

try to put in your third line command the following line:

```
strResult = crt.Screen.WaitForStrings(["open1","close1","open","close","SCAN"])
```

hope it helps!!